# How to show Enterprise Architect diagrams in Power Point in an appealing way?

Tags: architecture, powerpoint, diagram, enterprise-architect

I create my diagrams in Enterprise Architect.
Sometimes I need to embed them in Power Point presentations but it does not look good in the UI as it would if I would write them there from scratch.

Is there a way to do it nicely? Which tools would you recommend to manage a long persisting architecture and also present it nicely in presentations?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

EA is for making models - more functional than "pretty", so it sounds like you are using the wrong tool for the job.  However, I've been in the same boat - so I know exactly what you're talking about!

- I try and keep my diagrams as clean and presentable as possible - there's no doubt it contributes to making them more accessible.  This tends to work well for me.

Other possibilities.....

- Make dedicated "pretty" diagrams where necessary, and leave the more "serious" ones for the "real" work.  this might not be so viable depending on the size and complexity of the models (and the rate of change).
- Get a better tool.
- Give the raw diagram to someone like a designer and get them to do you a new "pretty" one.

Answer (score 1):

I strongly recommend the use of diagrams/UML as a **communication tool** as opposed to specifications (see http://martinfowler.com/bliki/UmlMode.html and http://fragmental.tw/2008/11/07/trying-to-write-architecture-specs-that-dont-suck-much-part-i-the-spec/).

That said, I often have to present diagrams to a larger audience using PowerPoint or Keynote slide decks. In presentations it is very important to keep in mind what the public you are presenting to already know about the architecture and technology and what to you want them to understand.

If you present to a group of executives the message has to be abstracted and probably your diagrams should use a very simple notation of boxes and arrows. If you are presenting at your local user group you probably can use more semantic constructs in your diagrams --like aggregations and inheritance-- but you probably will need to abstract-out most of the things that are specific to your company and people from outside don't know about (e.g. replace a module called "XPTO 1.0" with "Legacy Billing System").

Once you know what level of detail you should use you can get a tool. i'd recommend simple diagram tools like OmniGraffle or Visio. If you want more UML features than those tools provide you may try JudeUML, it creates quite clean diagrams that can be easily edited in a proper graphic editor.

I also recommend Dan Roam's "The Back of the Napkin" ( http://amzn.to/c5khDx ). It's a very interesting book on how simpler graphic models can be effective.

Answer (score 0):

Apologies that this is a bit off tangent, but I've always wondered what percentage of EA like modelling tools get used properly through a  project.

Of the instances I've used it was difficult to keep full round-tripping going and it was more used as a conceptual architecture tool to get the message across to the team. So a diagram tool with organized files normally work fine and gets my pretty diagrams.

@Adrian what do you term as 'real' work here?

Comment: By "real" I guess I just meant "engineering" - I think (probably as you do) that a good diagram (to support clear communication) is really important.  In terms of engineering, it's sometimes helpful to model requirements and Use Cases against parts of the system (for traceability); also, it helps you to manage dependencies and complex relationships as your enterprise models grow overtime.

Comment: Thanks Adrian. Yeah the traceability is a big win, however difficult to keep traceability via diagrams. Ideally should be like a wiki with links yet on the models.

Comment: Yes - you can't manage traceability via diagrams alone, you need a modelling tool that allows you to search you models for components, and one that also you to trace the relationships between entities.  One approach is to have a big nasty diagram that captures all/most of the relationships in your model (this diagram will be difficult for project newbies to understand), and then your other diagrams can focus on communication; this way you can de-couple the formal modelling from diagrams which are more for communication.